# J5 2015 operating system

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I had to factory reset my Samsung galaxy J5. While doing that it automatically upgraded my operating system/software.Can I restore old/previous one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find your device firmware on XDA or SamMobile. Download it and flash via Odin. You'll find the tutorial in the source most likely